# Caching Variables in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, caching

How can I cache variables in ASP.NET on page level? That is, I want to cache any variables that is loaded during the load cycle of the page, but once the page is fully loaded, I want the variable to be dumped.

**UPDATE:** I want the data to be cached on the server.

Comment: ViewState for single page, Session for all pages of a user

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: I am just a bit concerned about using ViewState and Session objects because I am afraid they might be sent with the request/response. What I want really is to cache the data on the server.

Comment: A 'Session' variable is stored in memory and is not sent with the request/response. Viewstate will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to declare your variables at the class level, e.g:

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
  private int _classVariable:

  pageLoad()
  {
     _classVariable = 1;
   }
}
```

Unless I'm missing something obvious

Comment: You are not missing anything actually, but it is the fact that I haven't done much with ASP.NET :-)

Answer (score 2):

Any variable declared in page_load would be visible during that process and removed automatically.

Anything needed at other states of the page lifecycle as well could be stored in a Session variable (or viewstate depending on where it is accessed) and removed when done with.

```
Session["value"] = value;

ViewState["value"] = value;
```

Comment: If it is declared in Page_Load, it will be garbage collected when the function exists! Am I missing something?

Comment: @promather Yes and as said, if you need it in multiple stages of page lifecycle, load it in the first use and store using sessions/viewstate and remove it when done. Personally, I would question why you are trying to do this in the first place.

Comment: Because there is some problem in the infrastructure of the page that causes thousands of records to be fetched from the database, and for each of those records we are making a request to a remote server to bind the record to a user. Since the users are only around 250, there is no point of doing the request thousands of time as opposed to just 250.

Comment: My suggestion would be to fix the actual problem then.

Comment: Well, I wish the world is as ideal as this :-) It is should a deep problem in the ORM of the project, so to fix the problem would take a month or so.

Answer (score 1):

There is one dictionary you cold use

```
Page.Items["variableName"] = yourObject;
```

you can access it from any control or user control or Page it self and it is shered to whole Page control tree

But if you don't need shared object, or you just need it per request in Page code behind make private field, it will be set to default on next request and you can change it to anything on Page_Load event

Answer (score 1):

You could cache the items in the [current HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) which are available for the duration of a request.

```
HttpContext.Current.Items["VariableName"] = value;
```

This would last the the lifetime of generating a page but can also be shared with other parts of your code that may want to interact with your page (http modules for example).